# Vi - ":call append()"

Tags: vi

Where can I learn about more commands like this using the "call" command? I can't seem to be able to type relevant keywords into google.

Answer (score 3):

"call" can call any vim function.
You can [write your own](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Write_your_own_Vim_function) function or use a built-in function.

To see all of the built-in functions and what they do, use

```
:help functions
```

in vim. Ctrl+] while viewing that list will toggle expanded function explanations. Use j/k as usual to scroll the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a Vim function to do basically anything, then call it using `:call func()`. The language is called vim script, it's not too difficult to learn. The vim wiki has [an excellent tutorial on the matter](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Write_your_own_Vim_function). [There's a wikibook on vim scripting as well.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_editor/Vim/Exim_Script_language)

So, to answer your question, the "call" command can do anything! It's whatever you program functions for.